# Problema peticion AJAX Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

estoy usando la [API de League Of Legends](https://developer.riotgames.com/) y quiero usar la url (tippo **GET**) que busca por **nombre de invocador**  la cual es la siguiente:

```
https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/AQUI_VA_EL_NOMBRE?api_key=AQUI_VA_MI_KEY
```

```
<script>
    //DATOS
    $key = "shh.. secreto..";
    $api_key = "?api_key="+$key;
    $api_url = "https://euw1.api.riotgames.com";


    $summoner_name = "NOMBRE QUE QUIERES BUSCAR";
    $api_url_summoner = "/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/"+$summoner_name+$api_key;

    $api_full_sumoner = $api_url+$api_url_summoner;



    $.ajax({
      url: $api_full_sumoner,
      type:'GET',
      success:  function (data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
</script>
```

Pero me dice el siguiente **error** la consola de firefox:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

y se refiere a esto : `$.ajax({....`

Comment: ¿Solo en firefox pasa esto?

Comment: Voy a probar en otro explorador. Pero igual es del ajax

Comment: no es el explorador

Comment: Procura mandar importar jQuery antes de importar tu código javascript

Comment: sisi, esta importado **antes**

Comment: agregarle `const` $key, $api_key, etc.. para ver si es ese el problema..

Comment: ejemplo:

`const $api_key = "?api_key="+$key;`

Comment: creo que es porque estoy importando jquery slim

Comment: agrega el codigo de importacion de tu libreria ,

Comment: solucionado, ahora el tema es el cors...

Comment: pero eso es del lado del servidor, si no soporta peticiones desde tu sitio, ya no hay nada que hacer, del lado del cliente

Comment: pero es  una api publica, que puedes acceder a sus difenrentes url (get), con poner tu API_KEY ya basta

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                /* Siguiendo la estructura de la peticion de la API que es la siguiente: */    
                //https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/RiotSchmick?api_key=<key>
                /* yo utilizaria el siguiente codigo, lamentablemente no cuento con la API KEY para realizar las pruebas 
                 pero con la informacion oficial de la pagina https://developer.riotgames.com/getting-started.html
                creo que esto te puede servir */
                var api_key = "shh.. secreto..";
                var summoner_name = "NOMBRE QUE QUIERES BUSCAR";
                $.getJSON("https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/" +
                            escape(summoner_name)  +
                            "?api_key="  +
                            api_key,
                function(json) {
                                var resultado = json.name[1].Value;
                                console.log(resultado);
                            });
                        return arguments.callee;
                    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas incluir la libreria de JQuery para poder utilizar Ajax.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: si revisas la zona de comentarios, el OP indica que ya esta importando dicha biblioteca